# Multiple Rows into Multiple Columns Dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

I'm relatively new to R and am trying to transpose a date frame of repeating rows into columns in a certain way. What I want is along the lines of spread() in tidyr, but I believe it's slightly different because I can't seem to get it right. Each record would be unique based on Company, Loc, and Type, with multiple Spec rows spread out as columns. There are varying number of Specs per unique record can be as many as 20 Specs.

What I have

```
Company    Loc         Type     Spec
100000012   104         51      363
100000012   104         51      431
100000012   104         51      508
100000012   104         51      512
100000012   104         51      513
100000012   126         51      513
100000012   166         53      530
100000012   42          51      516
100000012   43          53      530
100123545   50          52      513
100123545   50          52      363
```

What I want

```
Company    Loc         Type     Spec1  Spec2  Spec3  Spec4  Spec5
100000012   104         51      363     431    508    512    513
100000012   126         51      513
100000012   166         53      530
100000012   42          51      516
100000012   43          53      530
100123545   50          52      513     363
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), Company + Loc + Type ~
         paste0("Spec", rowid(Company, Loc, Type)), value.var = "Spec")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) and [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(Company, Loc) %>%
  mutate(ID = paste0("Spec", 1:n())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(ID, Spec) %>%
  select(c("Company", "Loc", "Type", paste0("Spec", 1:(ncol(.) - 3))))
dat2
# # A tibble: 6 x 8
#     Company   Loc  Type Spec1 Spec2 Spec3 Spec4 Spec5
#       <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 100000012    42    51   516    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 2 100000012    43    53   530    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 3 100000012   104    51   363   431   508   512   513
# 4 100000012   126    51   513    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 5 100000012   166    53   530    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 6 100123545    50    52   513   363    NA    NA    NA
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Company    Loc         Type     Spec
100000012   104         51      363
                  100000012   104         51      431
                  100000012   104         51      508
                  100000012   104         51      512
                  100000012   104         51      513
                  100000012   126         51      513
                  100000012   166         53      530
                  100000012   42          51      516
                  100000012   43          53      530
                  100123545   50          52      513
                  100123545   50          52      363",
                  header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this option and it looks to be good. When I did it on the larger dataset the Spec columns ordered as Spec1, Spec11, Spec 12, etc. instead of Spec1, Spec2, etc. I tried using "01" in mutate but that didn't fix. Anyway to fix with addition to the code above?

Comment: @JoeHafer Please see my update. The last `select` call is for arranging the columns.